# Create cross platform apps in ubuntu

Tags: java, .net, cross-platform, smartphone

I am using Ubuntu on my computer, and I do not want to switch to another operating system.

I'm looking for a software that would let me program cross platform apps (for smartphones) with one programming language.

I would prefer a .NET language. Yes, I have looked at Mono, but they only offer their software in Windows and Mac.

Is there a software that would let me build a cross platform app? (I don't like Java, but JavaScript is one that I can handle)

Comment: +1 for " I do not want to switch to another operating system"

Comment: *"(for smartphones)"*  I don't think there **is** a cross-platform language for phones.  E.G. Android needs Java.  iPhone needs ..something else.  Most phones support browsing with JS, so you might want to develop a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for a software that would let me program cross platform apps (for smartphones) with one programming language.

If you are looking for some tools for developing cross platform apps for smartphones, I suggest you [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

> Is there a software that would let me build a cross platform app? (I don't like Java, but JavaScript is one that I can handle)

You are using ubuntu and want to use .Net, No this is not a convenient solution. If you want a platform independent language, I absolutely suggest you, JAVA ;)

Please notice that:
Java **IS NOT** JavaScript and they are not related to each other.

Comment: Yes, I know Java and JavaScript are different. I did download PhoneGap, but I don't know how to start using it? How do I integrate it into an IDE (and which IDE)? Thanks.

Comment: Good :) .... [This links](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides) contains the full tutorials for getting started with PhoneGap. Suppose that you want to develop your app for Android, now you choose [Getting Started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) then after developing your app you can use [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/people/sign_up) to port your app for another platforms (ios, windows phone and ...) :)

Comment: It is said Java to JavaScript is as Car to Carpet!

Answer (score 1):

MONO is available for more than both Mac and Windows. It runs in Ubuntu and instructions can be obtained from [here](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/Building_MonoDevelop_on_Ubuntu).

iOS apps can unfortunately not be built without xcode, but the coding can easily be reused between Ubuntu and Mac. One software to checkout is [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) which allows you to use c# to develop iPhone and Android apps. I've been coding in .Net for a while, and I have to say that when I had to do a unix class project, MONO and Xamarin saved my life

Note: I know that your question specifically said you don't like the idea of switching platforms like you would need to in MONO, but I've done a lot of research on this and I've determined it to be my best option, I'd think it'll work for you if you're willing to use a Mac or PC

Comment: I like Mono. I said I don't like Java. That's why I was asking for alternative software to Mono, because I am running Ubuntu, and Mono (Xamarin) only runs on Mac or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I did come across [Appcelerator](https://www.appcelerator.com/). It seems that they supported Linux previously and the single language you can write in is Javascript.

It's not opensource. You have to make an account to download and install it, but there's free versions for solo developers. I'd rather use [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) to develop in Python though ;)

Good luck.